# How to install ZendFramework from svn on Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: php, xcode, macos, svn, zend-framework

I have a Macbook pro with Lion(10.7.4). I am new in this environment. I was trying to install Zend Framework in my mac. I already installed XAMPP and created svn and ZendFramework folder inside XAMPP root directory.

```
/Applications/XAMPP/svn/ZendFramework
```

But whenever I try to install ZendFramework it shows some information. May be I did not install svn in my mac before. I do not know how to do it. Or I do not know what is the problem. I already install XCODE. Should I need to install svn first then I have to install ZendFramework. If it is like this I have two questions-

1. How to install svn using XCODE?
2. How to install ZendFramework using
   svn?

Command Line Output:

```
$ svn checkout http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/svn
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
    /usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: The issue looks similar to the one at https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3243357. BTW it's completely unrelated to SVN. (SVN is pre-installed in Xcode).

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s libpq.5.3.dylib libpq.5.dylib
```

worked for me.